# Searching for username in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an android app integrating firebase, i want to have a functionality where user can search for other users using their name/username. I am currently using SearchView widget (want to employ onQueryTextChange())
For example if a user types code, then all the queries matching "code" (or starting with "code", either of them) shows up

Firebase structure:

```
users
    <uid of user1>
            name: ....
            username: .......
    <uid of user2>
            name: ....
            username: .......
    ...
    ...
```

Help me with time efficient solution (in java) for it so searching is fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the structure you have, if you want to only retrieve child nodes of `users` who have a `username` property with the value `"code"`, you can use a query to [order and filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) nodes. Something like this:

```
Query query = dbRoot.child("users").orderByChild("username").equalTo("code");
```

To execute the query, you'd do:

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.i("DB", userSnapshot.getKey());
            Log.i("DB", userSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class));
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

---

If you want to get all child nodes where the `username` **starts with** `"code"`, that'd be:

```
Query query = dbRoot.child("users")
  .orderByChild("username")
  .startAt("code")
  .endAt("code~");
```

Comment: what is the significance of 
.endAt("code~");

Comment: It's just a character late in the [ASCII character range](https://www.asciitable.com/), so that the query catches all nodes that are usually in the range.